Question on an integral with residues
I am trying to calculate the principal value of the following integral with the Residues' Theorem:
\begin{equation*}
I=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^{\lambda}(x-4)}dx
\end{equation*} with $\lambda\in (0,1)$. My idea was to integrate the holomorphic function
\begin{equation*}
f(z)=\frac{1}{z^{\lambda}(z-4)}
\end{equation*}
(where $\log(z)=\log|z|+i\arg(z)$ with $\arg(z)\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3}{2}\pi)$) over the path $\gamma=\gamma_1+\gamma_2+\gamma_3+\gamma_4+\gamma_5+\gamma_6$ shown in the following figure (pardon me for my terrible drawing "abilities")

with $r\rightarrow 0$ and $R\rightarrow +\infty$. I noticed that the integrals over the curves $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_3$ and $\gamma_5$ (the semi circumferences) approach $0$ because, e.g.
\begin{equation*}
\left|\int_{\gamma_1}\frac{1}{z^{\lambda}(z-4)}dz\right|\leq \int_{\gamma_1}\frac{1}{|z|^{\lambda}|z-4|}dz=\int_{\gamma_1}\frac{1}{r^{\lambda}|z-4|}dz\leq \frac{1}{r^{\lambda}|r-4|}\int_{\gamma_1}dz=\frac{1}{r^{\lambda}|r-4|}\cdot \pi r=\frac{\pi r^{1-\lambda}}{|r-4|} \rightarrow_{r\rightarrow 0} 0
\end{equation*}
(where I used the inequality: $|x-y|\geq ||x|-|y||$ and:
\begin{equation*}
\left|\int_{\gamma_5}\frac{1}{z^{\lambda}(z-4)}dz\right|\leq \int_{\gamma_5}\frac{1}{R^{\lambda}|z-4|}|dz|\leq \frac{1}{R^{\lambda}|R-4|}\pi R=\frac{\pi R^{1-\lambda}}{R-4}\rightarrow_{R\rightarrow +\infty} 0
\end{equation*}
because $\lambda\in (0,1)$. While,
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\gamma_6}f(z)dz \rightarrow \int_{-\infty}^0\frac{1}{t^{\lambda}(t-4)}dt=_{\tau=-t}(-1)^{1+\lambda}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\tau^{\lambda}(\tau+4)}d\tau
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\gamma_2}f(z)dz+\int_{\gamma_4}f(z)dz\rightarrow \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t^{\lambda}(t-4)}dt
\end{equation*}
Now, I have the following questions:
Is what I did correct?
I saw in another post that the principal value of this integral should be $\frac{\pi}{4^{\lambda}}\cot(\pi \lambda)$.....where does the cotangent come from?
$z=0$ is not a pole, it is and eliminating singularity, so $Res_{z=0}(f)=0$. However, when $r\rightarrow 0$, the curve $\gamma_1$ approaches $0$. What are the effects of this on the integral?
$z=4$ is a pole and $Res_{z=4}(f)=\frac{1}{4^{\lambda}}$. It can be shown that for $r\rightarrow 0$, the integral over a closed curve with a semi circumference which passes around $z=4$ approaches to $\frac{\pi i}{4^{\lambda}}$ for the radius of the semi circumference approaching to 0. In this expression $\cot(\pi \lambda)$ does not figure. This makes me think that there is another contribute in the integral over the whole curve $\gamma$. Is it perhaps that of $z=0$?
I am sorry; I am new to the method of residues and this is one of my first integrals calculated in this way.
Thanks in advance for any answer and help!

Are you sure that the integral over $\gamma_5$ approaches $0$? Note that you have to evaluate the limit as $R \to \infty$. Also, $(-1)^{1+\lambda}$ makes no sense in a real integral

I edited the post

I think the contour might not be appropriate: the integral over $\gamma_6$ would be helpful if you had to compute $I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^{\lambda}(x-4)}dx$. If you have access to it, I recommend having a look at "Complex Analysis with Applications" by Asmar and Grafakos, precisely examples 5.5.2 and 5.5.3. Your exercise is really similar to exercise 13 in section 5.5, which can be solved using the previous examples. There is also a solution manual which includes this exercise, but there's plenty of mistakes.

Here is the link to download this manual of solutions: https://extras.springer.com/?query=978-3-319-94062-5. I spotted many mistakes, for example it is not lemma 5.4.3 but 5.4.7; the indices of the curves are wrong: the first integral is actually $I_1$, but the following three should be $I_2 + I_4, I_6 + I_8, I_3 + I_7$. Despite the large amount of mistakes in this manual, which in fact I suggest that you avoid using, I strongly recommend reading the book

Okk, Thank you!!

Even though the substitution $x = e^t$ in your first integral would make things easier, I must say that I stumbled on your question. But I have just asked a new question related to yours: you might be interested in it, I suggest that you follow it.

Ok, I got it. Using that contour $\gamma=\gamma_1+...+\gamma_6$, I found that, using correctly the definition of the logarithm I chose, that the integrals over $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma_4$ approach together (I mean their sum) to the principal value of the integral
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{t^{\lambda}(t-4)}
\end{equation*}
while the integral over $\gamma_6$ approaches to
\begin{equation*}
-e^{-i\lambda \pi}\cdot PV\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{t^{\lambda}(t+4)}
\end{equation*}
and the integrals over the semicircular paths approach to zero as shown above. On the other hand, by the Residue theorem, it can be shown that for $r\rightarrow 0$ and $R\rightarrow +\infty$
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz \rightarrow \pi iRes_{z=4}(f)=\frac{\pi i}{4^{\lambda}}
\end{equation*}
Now, let's call
\begin{align*}
I&=PV\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t^{\lambda}(t-4)}dt\\
J&=-PV\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t^{\lambda}(t+4)}dt
\end{align*}
We obtain, for $r\rightarrow 0$ and $R\rightarrow +\infty$ the following equation:
\begin{equation*}
I+e^{-i\lambda \pi}J=\frac{\pi i}{4^{\lambda}}
\end{equation*}
which is equivalent to:
\begin{align*}
I+\cos(\lambda \pi)J&=0\\
-\sin(\lambda \pi)J&=\frac{\pi}{4^{\lambda}}
\end{align*}
Solving this simple system we finally have:
\begin{equation*}
I=\frac{\pi}{4^{\lambda}}\cot(\lambda \pi)
\end{equation*}
and $\cot(\lambda \pi)$ is well defined because $\lambda\in (0,1)$.
